# C# string format delimiter 12-3456789-0

Tags: c#, string-formatting

I have a below string.

```
1234567890
```

I want to get like that string.

```
12-3456789-0
```

I tried using below code.

```
string.Format("{0:0-#######-#}", "1234567890");
```

But result is not what I want.

```
1234567890
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Qzw4SS)

Comment: How could anyone can help community down voting without giving positive suggestion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason your code does not work is because you are specifying number-formatting for a string.

Look:

```
string.Format("{0:0-#######-#}", "1234567890"); // "1234567890" is a string
```

Try this instead:

```
string.Format("{0:0-#######-#}", 1234567890); // 1234567890 is a number
```

Incidentally, to get the output you actually say you want, your format string needs to be `{0:0#-#######-#}`

Answer (score 1):

You should use int value instead string, like:

```
using System;                   
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string s = "1234567890";
        int i = int.Parse(s);
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");       
        string test = string.Format("{0:0-#######-#}", i);
        Console.WriteLine(test);            
    }
}
```

Output:

> Hello World
>
> 12-3456789-0

You must use numeric type because you use [Custom Numeric Format String](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx)